# How to control page behavior of form after submitting in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I currently have two forms. One of them quits the app when I submit it and the other just says "row created" and stays on the page. I want both of them to redirect to my home page after submitting. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: What happens after a form is submitted is generally controlled by the branches on the page.  I would expect that one page has a branch that branches to a logout page of some sort and the other probably doesn't have a branch.  You can remove the first branch and add a new branch on each page that takes users to the home page.  You'd need to determine the conditions to define on the branch (i.e. branch on any page submission, only when certain buttons are pressed, only when the process was successful, etc.)

Comment: If you're unsure what is causing the behaviour, then you could run the app in debug and verify what exactly is happening. As @JustinCave explained - branches is what should be used.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use after submit Branches with server side condition.